# Phonetic Dictionary

Tags: resources

Does anyone know of a phonetic dictionary (such as this one http://www.writeexpress.com/phonetic.html) that works for Mac or is available online?

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://dictionary.reference.com and look up the word and then select "Show IPA" it shows you the pronunciation using the International Phonetic System which I love.